# Wifi drops out constantly after upgrade to xUbuntu 14.10

Tags: wireless, networking, upgrade, xubuntu

I upgraded yesterday from xUbuntu 14.04 to 14.10, because I hoped to have better bluetooth recognition. (I didn't).

### Before the upgrade

Wifi would drop out seemingly randomly. More often, when there was more space/stuff between me and my router, but also when nothing changed.

Time could be between 2 days and (in extreme cases) a few minutes.

I need to disable-enable the whole network by using the dropdown menu, because after losing connection the SSID of the router is not in the menu for me to choose. The router itself does not lose connection to any other device and I'm connected to it again after 5 seconds, after re-enabling the network.

### After the upgrade

Wifi drops out faster now ~10-30 minutes.

---

I already tried [this solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=13119513#post13119513). But it didn't work.

Output of '[The Script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205)' (too long): http://paste.ubuntu.com/9850671/

Any further information will be gladly provided. I would be very grateful for some help and even a little explanation what the problem is if possible.

### Update 1

```
Jan 24 17:21:37 Laptop kernel: [ 7755.037954] wlan0: deauthenticated from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (Reason: 7=CLASS3_FRAME_FROM_NONASSOC_STA)
```

This line appears everytime my connection drops. Might be connected with [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1293569)

### Update 2

For the time being, I made a script automatically reconnecting me.

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
        if ! ping -c 1 -W 4 192.168.2.1 >/dev/null; then
                notify-send 'Network gone down' 'Reconnecting...'
                nmcli nm enable false;
                sleep 0.5;
                nmcli nm enable true;
                sleep 10
        fi
        sleep 1
done
```

IP address might need to be changed. I'm not fit in networking. It may also produce some false positives. It is a hack, after all. Still better than manually clicking through menus every time.

### Update 3

Current output of 'The script': [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9870590/)

Cross posted the question to the [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2262629) as adviced.

Answer (score 0):

Change your router from auto or whatever channel it is on to a channel not occupied, the following is from the script and you are one of them on channel 11

```
Channel occupancy:

  1   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
  3   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
  1   APs on   Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
  5   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
```

The fix you found and the bug are not applicable to your wifi card, an Intel Centrino N135

One thing that could help with 11N speeds is `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` reboot and check results

Try disabling the Ubuntu firewall.

`sudo iw reg set DE` and reboot and possibly test with TLP disabled, the new results look like you should have a working wifi connection

Comment: I changed my channel to channel 1. Could you elaborate what 11N speeds mean? 802.11n?

Comment: 11n allows transfer speeds up to 600 Mbps whereas 11g allows up to 54 Mbps.  If you edit the file using `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` change the command to 11n_disable=1 it will disable 11n but still will allow 11 a/b/g

Comment: I added `11n_disable=8` to the conf file and restarted. Unfortunately it did not change anything. Changing it to `11n_disable=1` did not help either.

Comment: Disable firewall(UFW) as it is blocking some traffic it shouldn't

Comment: Will disable it with `sudo ufw disable` and report back. Can you explain, how you saw, that the `ufw` is messing up?

Comment: Line 917 from your wireless_script output and the final line is similar

Comment: I'm waiting for another disconnect before disabling the firewall, to weed out a possible false positive. So far it is stable for some reason. Changing `11n_disable` to 1 might have helped after all? Will investigate further and report back, once I have results.

Comment: Internet connection died the second I opened skype. Maybe just coincidence. Will disable the firewall now.

Comment: Disabling the firewall did also not help, unfortunately.

Comment: Reboot and run the wireless script again and post the new results

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: I tried setting `iw reg set DE` and rebooting. Don't know what TLP means, though. Sorry. No change.

Comment: You have some type of power management set up on it, disable it for some testing

Comment: Will try this: `iwconfig wlan0 power off` Hope that's what you meant.

Comment: Try this and reboot `sudo apt-get --purge remove tlp`

Comment: Did not work either, unfortunately. Considering reinstalling.

Comment: Something strange is going on, my own results on Ubuntu 14.10 from the script doesn't have results like yours on lines 650-800 + with lines referring to `CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp`  If you wish, post on ubuntuforums.org in networking and wireless.  I would reinstall 14.04 if wifi worked well then

Comment: Well is an overstatement. It's 1am, so I will post my case and all the information there tomorrow. Thank you for the time and effort you put into helping me, can I buy you a beer or something in return?